# Dart: split a list to two sublists based on condition

Tags: list, dart

Have there any way to split a list in dart based on a condition like following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] (A sample list)

After splitting it based on i % 2 == 0 condition, 
it would generate the following two lists:
1) [1, 3, 5, 7]
2) [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I know I can simply write a loop to go through all the elements and check the condition to create the two sublists. But have there any shorter functional way in dart?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this a lot it could be a good idea to create an extension method in your project which does what you want. I have come up with the following design which should work in a generic and efficient way:

```
void main() {
  final s_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  final match = s_list.splitMatch((element) => element % 2 == 0);

  print(match.matched);   // [2, 4, 6, 8]
  print(match.unmatched); // [1, 3, 5, 7]
}

extension SplitMatch<T> on List<T> {
  ListMatch<T> splitMatch(bool Function(T element) matchFunction) {
    final listMatch = ListMatch<T>();

    for (final element in this) {
      if (matchFunction(element)) {
        listMatch.matched.add(element);
      } else {
        listMatch.unmatched.add(element);
      }
    }

    return listMatch;
  }
}

class ListMatch<T> {
  List<T> matched = <T>[];
  List<T> unmatched = <T>[];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution:

```
var s_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

s_list.where( (el) => el % 2 == 0 ).toList();
s_list.where( (el) => el % 2 != 0 ).toList();
```